# Right way to center-align contents of a div

Tags: html, css, layout

I have this page that I just added an ad to on the right side:

http://www.comehike.com/hikes/search_hikes.php?redirect=yes&radius=&postal_code=

I tried to wrap it in a  tag, but that didn't work in this case.  Any way I can simply make the ad get centered there instead of floating right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see you have applied '1em' padding to the left of you div (shown below in the code taken from your stylesheet) which is what is causing your advert to move out of the range of your DIV (I think).

```
.content .chapter div {
    padding-left: 1em;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Try adding a class or id to the div containing the iframe of your ad and setting

```
padding-left: 0px;
```

Good Luck.

Answer (score 2):

The `padding-left: 1em` on `.content .chapter div` is throwing it off. Try removing that property.

Comment: Actually, that might mess up other things. Is it possible to make a new div just for that content with something like this: <div style="float: center;">

Comment: I took it off and it didn't change anything on the page except that ad.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this CSS style:

```
margin:0 auto
```

and if that doesn't work put a margin on the right by using:

```
margin-right:10px;
```